# Why does the camera in unity keep falling and losing track of player as if it had gravity enabled?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello I was trying to build my first 2D game using a video I saw on youtube. The thing is the camera keeps on moving downwards and away from the game character.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add all relevant information like e.g. the video link and in particular the code you implemented. Currently it is hard to tell what you are talking about

Comment: We need more information or pictures, try add some of your inspector

Answer (score -2):

Create a new camera and make sure the view is on your player.

Go to Window -> Package Manager and search for Cinemachine.

Import Cinemachine Package.

Create new Cinemachine 2D camera and set it's Follow to your player gameObject.

More information would also help.